# git rebase getting invalid upstream

Tags: git

I did the following:

**git fetch --all**

**git checkout -b my-feature-branch master**

// did some edits

**git commit -m "some commit comments"**

**git rebase another-branch**

I get git error: "invalid upstream 'another-branch'

I can see the 'another-branch' on the remote so I am not sure what is happening. Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Do you see 'another-branch' locally?

Comment: I see only master and *my-feature-branch

Comment: Did you try `git rebase origin/another-branch`?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You need to checkout 'another-branch' locally before rebasing it.

```
git checkout -b another-branch origin/another-branch
```

Or, you need to pull all the branch after fetching

```
git pull --all
```

Comment: would not I lose my committed changes in my feature branch if I checkout the 'another-branch'? what I am trying to do is rebase my committed changes(not pushed) from my-feature-branch onto 'another-branch'

Comment: No, if you committed, it will be there locally

Comment: Thanks for your help Abimaran.

Answer (score 2):

For me, I had a really old feature branch and ran into this error even though I ran a fetch in advance. I solved it by checking out the new (just fetched) release branch, checking the feature dev branch out again, and then doing the rebase.

```
$ git fetch --all
...
010c8a1..48202ec  release/new    -> origin/release/new
...

$ git branch
...
* dev/featurebranch (currently based on 'release/old')

$ git rebase release/new
fatal: invalid upstream 'release/new'

$ git checkout release/new
branch release/new set up to track origin/release/new by rebasing.
Switch to a new branch 'release/new'

$ git checkout dev/featurebranch
switched to branch...

$ git rebase release/new
Successfully rebased and updated refs/heads/dev/featurebranch
```

I think, but am not sure, that the crux of why the second rebase worked is that `branch <name> set up to track origin/<name> by rebasing` created a local release branch to follow the origin release branch, which is what the local dev branch is technically rebased on top of.

Comment: Ahh, despite "successfully" rebasing, I did still have to resolve conflicts after doing `git pull` which I think is what was lacking about my `git fetch` (maybe I could've finished it with a `git merge` or something like that to finalize) vs the accepted answer's "or do a `git pull --all`" which makes sense to me (more than the first part of that answer, which is why I didn't try that).

Answer (score 1):

**Cherry pick to the rescue (again)**

In my case, I had two branches with no common ancestor. (It was a new repo created on the server by admin staff but I wanted to get a head start on what I was building locally).

After adding a remote named 'origin' and fetching `main` branch, I needed to rebase my wholly-local branch (`spike`) onto the fetched branch (`main`).

My solution was to cherry pick all my commits from `spike` onto `main`.